# Screen blinking while unlocking the system Dell Vostro 3568

Tags: 18.04, dell, screen, login-screen

I have a Dell Vostro 15 3568 with Ubuntu 18.04.3 which starts blinking after 
the system gets locked and I want to unlock it again.

I just completed the fresh installation.

Sometimes, the blinking stopped after I tried to guess the screen while blinking and enter the password and sometimes it keeps on blinking after login as well.
Here, it is showing random behaviour after unlocking the system.

I have also tried with 19.10 but the issue didn't get resolved.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the result of **uname -a**

```
Linux Bigstep-Vostro-15-3568 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Result of **lshw**

```
description: Laptop
product: Vostro 15-3568 (0793)
vendor: Dell Inc.
serial: 2RCPNJ2
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 smp vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=docking family=Vostro sku=0793 uuid=44454C4C-5200-1043-8050-B2C04F4E4A32
*-core
description: Motherboard
product: 05HRPP
vendor: Dell Inc.
physical id: 0
version: A00
serial: /2RCPNJ2/CNWSC0078H02YK/
*-firmware
description: BIOS
vendor: Dell Inc.
physical id: 0
version: 01.08.00
date: 03/23/2017
size: 64KiB
capacity: 15MiB
capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
*-memory
description: System Memory
physical id: 3d
slot: System board or motherboard
size: 8GiB
*-bank:0
description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
product: 9905711-005.A00G
vendor: Synertek
physical id: 0
serial: 89106A96
slot: DIMM A
size: 4GiB
width: 64 bits
clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
*-bank:1
description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
product: HMA851S6AFR6N-UH
vendor: Synertek
physical id: 1
serial: 2980DE7F
slot: DIMM B
size: 4GiB
width: 64 bits
clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
*-cache:0
description: L1 cache
physical id: 41
slot: L1 Cache
size: 128KiB
capacity: 128KiB
capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
configuration: level=1
*-cache:1
description: L2 cache
physical id: 42
slot: L2 Cache
size: 512KiB
capacity: 512KiB
capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
configuration: level=2
*-cache:2
description: L3 cache
physical id: 43
slot: L3 Cache
size: 3MiB
capacity: 3MiB
capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
configuration: level=3
*-cpu
description: CPU
product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
vendor: Intel Corp.
physical id: 44
bus info: cpu@0
version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
slot: U3E1
size: 500MHz
capacity: 2GHz
width: 64 bits
clock: 100MHz
capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
*-pci
description: Host bridge
product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 100
bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
version: 08
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
configuration: driver=skl_uncore
resources: irq:0
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 07
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:128 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
*-generic:0
description: Signal processing controller
product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 4
bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
version: 08
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: msi pm cap_list
configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
resources: irq:16 memory:d1320000-d1327fff
*-usb
description: USB controller
product: Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 14
bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
version: 21
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
resources: irq:124 memory:d1310000-d131ffff
*-usbhost:0
product: xHCI Host Controller
vendor: Linux 5.3.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
physical id: 0
bus info: usb@1
logical name: usb1
version: 5.03
capabilities: usb-2.00
configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
*-usb:0
description: Mass storage device
product: v236w
vendor: HP
physical id: 1
bus info: usb@1:1
logical name: scsi2
version: 1.00
serial: 6E008B8FAC824A81
capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
*-disk
description: SCSI Disk
product: v236w
vendor: hp
physical id: 0.0.0
bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
logical name: /dev/sdb
version: PMAP
serial: 64EA08018
size: 14GiB (15GB)
capabilities: removable
configuration: ansiversion=4 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
*-medium
physical id: 0
logical name: /dev/sdb
size: 14GiB (15GB)
capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
configuration: signature=7c16839e
*-volume
description: Windows FAT volume
vendor: mkfs.fat
physical id: 1
logical name: /dev/sdb1
logical name: /media/bigstep/bigstep
version: FAT32
serial: ad1f-05ad
size: 14GiB
capacity: 14GiB
capabilities: primary fat initialized
configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=bigstep mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
*-usb:1
description: Video
product: Integrated Webcam
vendor: CNFFH36N293082053892
physical id: 5
bus info: usb@1:5
version: 65.10
serial: 0x0001
capabilities: usb-2.00
configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
*-usb:2
description: Generic USB device
product: USB2.0-CRW
vendor: Generic
physical id: 6
bus info: usb@1:6
version: 39.60
serial: 20100201396000000
capabilities: usb-2.00
configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
*-usb:3
description: Bluetooth wireless interface
vendor: Atheros Communications, Inc.
physical id: 8
bus info: usb@1:8
version: 0.01
capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.01
configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
*-usbhost:1
product: xHCI Host Controller
vendor: Linux 5.3.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
physical id: 1
bus info: usb@2
logical name: usb2
version: 5.03
capabilities: usb-3.00
configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
*-generic:1
description: Signal processing controller
product: Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 14.2
bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
version: 21
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi cap_list
configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
resources: irq:18 memory:d1338000-d1338fff
*-generic:2
description: Signal processing controller
product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 15
bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
version: 21
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
resources: irq:16 memory:d1337000-d1337fff
*-generic:3
description: Signal processing controller
product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 15.1
bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
version: 21
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
resources: irq:17 memory:d1336000-d1336fff
*-communication
description: Communication controller
product: Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 16
bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
version: 21
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
resources: irq:127 memory:d1335000-d1335fff
*-storage
description: SATA controller
product: Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 17
bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
version: 21
width: 32 bits
clock: 66MHz
capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
resources: irq:125 memory:d1330000-d1331fff memory:d1334000-d13340ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:d1333000-d13337ff
*-pci:0
description: PCI bridge
product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1c
bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
version: f1
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=pcieport
resources: irq:122 memory:d1000000-d11fffff
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: wlp1s0
version: 31
serial: e8:9e:b4:13:54:1d
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.3.0-28-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.1.78 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:130 memory:d1000000-d11fffff
*-pci:1
description: PCI bridge
product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1c.5
bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
version: f1
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=pcieport
resources: irq:123 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:d1200000-d12fffff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: enp2s0
version: 0c
serial: 10:7d:1a:38:fa:59
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d1204000-d1204fff memory:d1200000-d1203fff
*-isa
description: ISA bridge
product: Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1f
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
version: 21
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: isa bus_master
configuration: latency=0
*-memory UNCLAIMED
description: Memory controller
product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1f.2
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
version: 21
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:d132c000-d132ffff
*-multimedia
description: Audio device
product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1f.3
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
version: 21
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
resources: irq:129 memory:d1328000-d132bfff memory:d1300000-d130ffff
*-serial UNCLAIMED
description: SMBus
product: Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1f.4
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
version: 21
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:d1332000-d13320ff ioport:f040(size=32)
*-scsi:0
physical id: 1
logical name: scsi0
capabilities: emulated
*-disk
description: ATA Disk
product: ST1000LM035-1RK1
vendor: Seagate
physical id: 0.0.0
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
logical name: /dev/sda
version: SDM2
serial: WDEF26A2
size: 931GiB (1TB)
capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=4daec86d-b2e0-4cd9-a4c2-8179c1406999 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
*-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
description: Windows FAT volume
vendor: mkfs.fat
physical id: 1
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
version: FAT32
serial: e9ca-91f3
size: 974MiB
capacity: 975MiB
capabilities: boot fat initialized
configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
*-volume:1
description: Linux swap volume
vendor: Linux
physical id: 2
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
logical name: /dev/sda2
version: 1
serial: 0ed1813f-64a2-464a-ba30-9452f29a8884
size: 9763MiB
capacity: 9765MiB
capabilities: nofs swap initialized
configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
*-volume:2
description: EXT4 volume
vendor: Linux
physical id: 3
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
logical name: /dev/sda3
logical name: /boot
version: 1.0
serial: 13fc88bc-41cf-4cc2-bb2b-d8ae42c7c409
size: 977MiB
capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
configuration: created=2020-02-17 18:31:16 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2020-02-18 11:44:14 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2020-02-18 11:44:14 state=mounted
*-volume:3
description: EXT4 volume
vendor: Linux
physical id: 4
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
logical name: /dev/sda4
logical name: /home
version: 1.0
serial: 25c6b881-6b4a-44ec-a75f-6ef1eff4913c
size: 762GiB
capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
configuration: created=2020-02-17 18:31:17 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/home modified=2020-02-18 11:44:15 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2020-02-18 11:44:15 state=mounted
*-volume:4
description: EXT4 volume
vendor: Linux
physical id: 5
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
logical name: /dev/sda5
logical name: /
version: 1.0
serial: 5606fffe-8c25-4e11-8878-922a30625e8c
size: 157GiB
capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
configuration: created=2020-02-17 18:31:28 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2020-02-18 11:43:57 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2020-02-18 11:44:02 state=mounted
*-scsi:1
physical id: 2
logical name: scsi1
capabilities: emulated
*-cdrom
description: DVD-RAM writer
product: DVD+-RW GU90N
vendor: HL-DT-ST
physical id: 0.0.0
bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
logical name: /dev/cdrom
logical name: /dev/cdrw
logical name: /dev/dvd
logical name: /dev/dvdrw
logical name: /dev/sr0
version: A1C1
capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
*-battery
product: DELL VN3N047
vendor: SMP
physical id: 1
version: 12/06/2016
serial: 2A40
slot: Sys. Battery Bay
capacity: 41440mWh
configuration: voltage=14.8V
```

Here is the syslog

```
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (WW) modeset(0): hotplug event: connector 86's link-state is BAD, tried resetting the current mode. You may be leftwith a black screen if this fails...
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5573
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0 76.42 1366 1434 1479 1592 768 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (48.0 kHz eP)
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0 60.45 1366 1429 1470 1572 768 772 778 801 +hsync -vsync (38.5 kHz e)
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (WW) modeset(0): hotplug event: connector 86's link-state is BAD, tried resetting the current mode. You may be leftwith a black screen if this fails...
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5573
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0 76.42 1366 1434 1479 1592 768 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (48.0 kHz eP)
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0 60.45 1366 1429 1470 1572 768 772 778 801 +hsync -vsync (38.5 kHz e)
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (WW) modeset(0): hotplug event: connector 86's link-state is BAD, tried resetting the current mode. You may be leftwith a black screen if this fails...
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 5573
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0 76.42 1366 1434 1479 1592 768 772 779 800 +hsync -vsync (48.0 kHz eP)
  Vostro-15-3568 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1734]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0 60.45 1366 1429 1470 1572 768 772 778 801 +hsync -vsync (38.5 kHz e)
```